# Did they increase RAM in iPad 2?

Tags: memory, ipad

Since there was no hint about more RAM during the presentation yesterday, did anyone find out if they stay with 256 or (like iPhone 4) increased it at least up to 512?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question at the moment. Probably only after iFixit does its job on one…

Answer (score 8):

Apple never releases information about memory. The current rumour is 512 MB. You should wait until some opens it up (e.g. iFixit).

And there you go . [iPad-2-Wi-Fi-Teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPad-2-Wi-Fi-Teardown/5071/2). 512 MB of Samsung manufactured RAM.

[image: Step 13 on the logic]

Comment: Any reason why they don't tell us about RAM? Their specs page has everything but the RAM, bit strange.

Comment: Could be all marketing and content control. It sounds like something they did not want consumers comparing against other products/competitors...it really cannot be used as a valid indicator for purchase in the same way as a laptop. If I saw it up there in the specifications, I would think that they would have definitely played that out in the Keynote.

Comment: @Philippe … additionally they are using their own processor, which makes comparing/benchmarking it based on some "numbers" even more impossible. As you say, nowadays you cant really tell the speed of such a device based on these anyway and Apple Marketing does a good job at letting users find out the speed by "feeling" rather than "numbers".

Comment: I think they don't tell you because they want it to be an appliance. You don't know how much RAM is in your fridge or DVD player and I think Apple want the iPad to be be the same. Plus of course the iPad is magic, and nothing magical has RAM in it.

Comment: @MikeyByCrikey - But I *DO* know how much RAM my fridge and DVD player have, and I incorporate such information into the decision making process when deciding to buy products.

Comment: @MikeyByCrikey - Also, "Magic" just means no one has figured out how it works, and is a detrimental shortcut to critical thinking. I'd argue that it is actually a pejorative term.

Answer (score 1):

You know, I know how much RAM is in the devices I choose as well. I used to be such a predictor of how well a device functions, but I have to admit that Apple's latest round of iOS devices make me not really care anymore. Why worry about when it functions so smoothly. I for one hope more hardware manufacturer's adopt this philosophy, "Make it work well as an integrated device, not as a combination of desperate gadets".